# Cakephp xml serialize not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting below error when using XML serialize function.

```
Warning (2): get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given [CORE/cake/libs/xml.php, line 208]

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Xml::addAttribute() in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/xml.php on line 283
```

I have copy pasted the array that is being serialized below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [longitude] => 12
                    [latitude] => 1
                    [firstname] => Jae
                    [surname] => Choi
                    [profile_pic] => /img/files/test.jpeg
                    [facebook_id] => 12
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [distance] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [longitude] => 12
                    [latitude] => 1
                    [firstname] => 
                    [surname] => 
                    [profile_pic] => 
                    [facebook_id] => 13
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [distance] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [longitude] => -37.816
                    [latitude] => -37.811
                    [firstname] => Jae1
                    [surname] => Choi1
                    [profile_pic] => /img/files/test1.jpeg
                    [facebook_id] => 21
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [distance] => 6679.12217489041
                )

        )

)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. If someone can help out, that would be appreciated.

Thank you.
Jae

Comment: _'get_class() expects parameter 1 to be **object**'_ versus _'I have copy pasted the **array**'_. You can't give that function an array apparently, it only takes objects. Someone with more experience with CakePHP might tell you what other function to use.

Comment: Can you post the line you're using to serialize the object to XML?